# Why is this Node snippet not catching rejected Promise?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, bluebird

I'm trying to understand why a Promise rejection exception I've encountered is not being 
handled by my initial try/catch in the following code (full code is in [this branch](https://github.com/jaymell/nodeCf/tree/saveOutputs))

In this particular error, `nodeCf.deploy` is being called in index.js.

The error is happening because I should be using `this.deployName`, not `stack.deployName`
in my console.log statement.

The thing I don't understand is why this is considered an unhandle Promise rejection.
Shouldn't the try/catch I have in the initial call to nodeCf.deploy catch this?

```
// index.js:

  switch (args.action) {
    case 'deploy':
      try {
        await nodeCf.deploy(stacks, envVars);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`deployment failed: `, e);
        process.exit(1);
      }
      break;
  < ... >

// nodeCf module:
async deploy(stacks, envVars) {
  var stackOutputs = {};
  await Promise.each(stacks, async(stack) => {
    stackOutputs[stack.name] = await stack.deploy(envVars, 
      stackOutputs).outputs;
  });
}

// stack.deploy:
async deploy(envVars, stackOutputs) {
this.load(envVars, stackOutputs);
await ensureBucket(this.infraBucket);
const s3Resp = await this.uploadTemplate()
const stackResp = await ensureAwsCfStack({
  StackName: this.deployName,
  Parameters: this.parameters,
  Tags: this.tags,
  TemplateURL: s3Resp.Location,
  Capabilities: [ 'CAPABILITY_IAM', 
    'CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM' ]
});
this.outputs = _.map(stackResp.Outputs, (it) => 
  _(it).pick(['OutputKey', 'OutputValue'])
    .toPairs()
    .unzip()
    .tail()
    .fromPairs()
    .value());
console.log(`deployed ${stack.deployName}`); // 'stack' is causing exception
return this;
}
```

Comment: What is `Promise.each`?

Comment: Important part is that Bluebird is used (.each). And its callback isn't supposed to be async function.

Comment: @estus Ah, thanks. However, that should not be a problem: [*If the iterator function returns a promise or a thenable, then the result of the promise is awaited before continuing with next iteration.*](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html)

Comment: @Bergi Good call, that's true. Had this problem with Bluebird docs before, interface summary doesn't always match the description. Found that Bluebird TS typings are generally more informative and faithful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's your problem:

> ```
> stackOutputs[stack.name] = await stack.deploy(envVars, stackOutputs).outputs;
> ```

Notice that `stack.deploy` is an `async function`? That means it returns a promise - not the instance with the `outputs` property. You are accessing `.outputs` on the promise, which is `undefined`, which will be `await`ed just fine, but the promise and its rejection are ignored.

You'll need to write

```
stackOutputs[stack.name] = (await stack.deploy(envVars, stackOutputs)).outputs;
//                         ^                                         ^
```

or use a helper variable for the instance.